# DB connect function takes too much time - PHP

Tags: php, database, function, database-connection

I have the following DB connect function :

```
    function execute_query($select_query) {
         $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123","site_db");
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
          {
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
          return false;
          }
        else{
           $result = mysqli_query($con, $select_query);
           return $result;
            }
    }
```

And the following code in the PHP page (which displaying the all the data from the table):

```
 require_once('../lib/common/db_connect.php');

    $result= execute_query('SELECT typeID, articleID, articleTitle FROM articles');
```

The problem is that it's take too much time untill the page load (there only 10 rows in the table with not too much data).

I tried to write the connection in the current page:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123","site_db");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      return false;
      }

$result= mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT typeID, articleID, articleTitle FROM articles');
```

And than it was fast.

My question is why ot's take so much time when the connection code is in seperate function on seperate file?

Comment: I've seen no differences. May you have some harddisk problem, to execute require_once('../lib/common/db_connect.php'); ?

Answer (score 0):

[require_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) is a great deal slower than  [require](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php). However the difference shouln't be noticeable when you only require a few files, especially not when you require only one file.

My guess is that there is something wrong with your server environment. On what kind of system are you running the PHP script? It could be that *../lib* is stored on a different hard drive. Maybe the drive is damaged or stored on a remote location, which causes it to be very slowly read by the PHP interpreter.